# "Parameter client_assertion_type is missing" in keycloak

Tags: java, wildfly, keycloak, superuser

I am trying out get the access token from the super user so that I can the same to create new users in key cloak, I have deployed keycloak in wildfly and when I try to do the get call, I am getting `Invalid user credentials` as response,
How to know the actual credentials?
[image]

And when I try to update the password from the console, I getting the error message like below.

[image]

Since I am new to this and din't find enough information from internet also, any kind of help will be appreciated .

Updated:

Now i am getting new error description as `Parameter client_assertion_type is missing` like below. What should be `client_assertion_type` here ?

[image]

Comment: Use Keycloak Java client library `keycloak-admin-client` for creating new users.

Comment: @ravthiru ... but i need access token from superuser

Comment: @ravthiru ... I checked the documentation , nowhere mentioned what is the superuser password

Comment: have you tried with default values username=admin  and  password=password

Comment: yes, still getting invalid credentials

Comment: @Jet Please try the whole password all in CapsLock + number or marks (alphanumeric keys)

Comment: @Fmanin ... You mean from the console? I have tried and got the same exception `Failed to reset the password`

Comment: @Jet In both should it comes through (Console (CLI) or  UI) at least your password must contain 12 characters

Answer (score 7):

[This keycloak help page](https://www.keycloak.org/docs/6.0/securing_apps/index.html#_troubleshooting_2) describes the most likely reason for the second error:

> Q: When logging in, I get an error: *Parameter client_assertion_type is missing [invalid_client].
>
> A: This error means your client is configured with Signed JWT token credentials, which means you have to use the --keystore parameter when logging in.

Alternatively you can disable using JWT tokens for the client in Keycloak.

Comment: Hello. Where do you use the --keystore

Answer (score 2):

For your information, the `client_assertion_type` would probably be `urn:ietf:params:oauth:client-assertion-type:jwt-bearer`. But then you'd get another error because the `client_assertion` is missing.

If `ccp-portal` is a confidential client using client authentication with signed JWT then [the Keycloak doc](https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/securing_apps/#_client_authentication_adapter) states that

> During authentication, the client generates a JWT token and signs it
>   with its private key and sends it to Keycloak in the particular
>   backchannel request (for example, code-to-token request) in the
>   client_assertion parameter.

- I guess it's not possible to generate a JWT with PostMan.
- This is meant for backchannel client-keycloak communication, not for
  user authentication.

**Solutions**

- You can use the `admin-cli` as `client_id` instead of your `ccp-portal` client. The `admin-cli` should be in the list of clients configured for your `ccp` realm. You can see that from the Keycloak interface.
- Another option is allow direct access grants in `ccp-portal` client config.
- Finally you could use `ccp-portal` client in your application configured with one of the Keycloak client adapters, instead of POSTMan.

As subrob sugrobych mentionned, parameters should be passed as form-data.

Answer (score 1):

first of all, when you are posting data to keycloak over a rest client, you need to input parameters as *form* paramaters, and not as query parameters. This is why you are getting this strange error of not providing parameter grant_type, when you obviously are providing it. Same is valid for accessing keycloak api via code.

Next thing you need to think about are roles for your superuser. You can assign realm roles and client roles. There is a client named 'realm-management' which contains roles which would normally count as "system roles". You will need to use them. When you are getting HTTP code 403, it means, that probably your user is missing a role from this client.

Comment: I have updated the question with new error description, plz check

Comment: It also says 'Invalid Client'. may be you are missspelling its name?

Comment: it is correct and all of sudden started getting this error

Comment: Hi, when you look at keycloaks code, you'll see, that client_assertion_type can have value 'urn:ietf:params:oauth:client-assertion-type:jwt-bearer' and, when you pass it (or when this is required) you also need to pass client_assertion, which should contain a "sighning token".
KeyCloak requires this parameter when "signing token" is set in your configuration. So it must be set in your realm or in JSON in your web app. Please provide it for further investigation

Comment: ok, I dint find the `signing token` when i searched in realm. Do I need to set it or it will be set by default and I just need to use it ?

Comment: @ subrob ........ I have added registration access token and the issue came now is...... {
    "error_description": "Client authentication with signed JWT failed: Can't identify client. Issuer missing on JWT token",
    "error": "unauthorized_client"
}